# Advice needed on class design - fill a vector in a thread or return a future

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, vector, future

I am writing a class which is supposed to run different time consuming operations in background. First it fetches some sort of data from remote host and must provide it back to the user wrapped in some sort of container - vector. Then it should periodically send notifications to remote host. The result of sending notifications is not needed. It is also possible that class would be asked multiple times to fetch data from remote host, but notification sending is prohibited at that point. So I am hesitating what approach to chose.

For sending notifications periodically the most obvious that comes to mind is to create a thread and post tasks periodically. For fetching data async it feels like std::future would be a more reasonable approach, but then I am worried my class would look scary with having all this different stuff at the same time, rather than sticking to one of those.

```cpp
class ThreadAndFutureClient
{
public:
    std::future<std::vector<Entry>> get_entries();

    // post to thread
    void send_notification();

// ok, we may assume this is hidden in pimpl, so not visible to the user,
// but still the presence of two buggs me a little
private:
    std::thread thread_;
}
```

or

```cpp
class TheAllThreadClient
{
public:
    // post to thread
    void fetch_entries();

    // post to thread
    void send_notification();

    // return false if fetch entries is running in a thread currently,
    // return true if fetch entries is not running and fill in vector with fetched data
    bool get_entries(std::vector<Entry>& vector);


private:
    std::thread thread_;
}
```

Comment: Ask 10 programmers how to design something, and get 40 answers. Personally, I'd probably use a thread and callbacks rather than futures, unless the thread you're posting back to needs to synchronize on this eventually.

Comment: Thank you @JosephLarson How would you pass back vector with callbacks?

Comment: You probably need a tutorial on callbacks in C++. It's just a pointer to a function, and functions take arguments. Google for "c++ callbacks" or "c++ std::function examples" or something like that. Or learn how to use lambdas in C++. They're very very helpful.